# Azure Blob Storage with Python, create containers but not list them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure Blob Storage v12.13.1
Python 3.9.15

I have no problem creating containers...

```
    ## Create the container
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=sas_url)
    container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
```

but when I go to list them

```
all_containers = blob_service_client.list_containers()
for i,r in enumerate(all_containers):
    print(r)
```

I get this error...
HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:a04349e6-b01e-0010-58ac-fa6495000000

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: How are you instantiating blob service client?

Comment: Hey @GauravMantri, edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you are encountering this error is because your SAS token does not have `list (l)` permission.

Please try creating a blob service client with a SAS URL that has list permission in it.

Comment: I have no idea....I could have sworn I had that checked but I guess not - thank you!